# Is it possible to reuse a consumer in apache kafka using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Just wondering if it is possible to reuse a consumer in a python script when its run ?

I am using heroku kafka for data streaming and have a python script that uses the kafka-python library to connect to the broker. When the script is run, a new consumer group will be created. However, Heroku restarts my script at least once a daily and i cannot stop the restart. Therefore, each time the script is restarted, a new consumer is created and i have rebalancing issues.

Just wondering how in the script i can use an old existing consumer to consume data from a topic?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you giving a group id to the Python consumer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a consumer group before and pass it to script when a new consumer is created.If you pass consumer group name whenever you are are creating consumer , Apache wont create new consumer group.see following code to pass consumer group detail using shell

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topicName --group [consumer group name]
```